What is syntax for the filter block in terraform?
I have experimented many sorts of filters in terraform using regex and without using regex etc. However, Its still confusing if there are other attributes(other than name, value and regex) which can help me simplify my task. I have tried to search for the syntax in many websites including the official HCL website. Is there a documentation on the filter block syntax?
Thanks in advance.

You need to show what specific Terraform provider and resources you are working with. The filter is not a feature of Terraform, it is a feature of certain data sources in some Terraform providers, like the AWS Terraform provider.



filter {
  name   = "attribute-name"
  values = ["value1", "value2"]
}





resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # Instance configuration...

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["example-instance"]
  }
}




What does it mean to have a filter on a resource "aws_instance"? I think you mean to show that on a data "aws_instance" perhaps?
